# JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on line 4; I Don't Know What I Did Wrong

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm trying to get a user to write a sentence and then have the computer confirm each word in a separate "confirm window" without using spaces. 
In order to figure out if this code is the correct code to do this task I have to run the code, but 
I'm getting the error listed in the title for line four. First, I don't understand what the error is saying. And if it is telling me that on line four the `if`statement is not a function and it can not run it, then how come?

```
<script>
function sentenceFinder (sentence){
    for (counter = 0; counter < sentence.length; counter++){
        if (sentence.substring(counter, counter + 1) !== " "){
            words.push(sentence.substring(counter, counter + 1));
        }
        else {
            comfirm(words[0]);
        }
     };
}

var x = prompt("Please type in the sentence that will be seperated.")
sentenceFinder(x)

var words = []
</script>
```

Comment: What is `counter.subscript`? I think you mean `counter.substr`.

Comment: I think in your code you are using some wrong inbuilt function , means inbuilt function with some spelling mistake or wrong inbuilt function

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues which are causing errors.

1. You are using `subscript` where I think you intended to use `substring`.
2. You are using `words` before you set it to an array.

I think this is what you intended to write.

```
function sentenceFinder (sentence){
    for (counter = 0; counter < sentence.length; counter++){
        if (sentence.substring(counter, counter + 1) !== " "){
            words.push(sentence.substring(counter, counter + 1));
        }
        else {
            comfirm(words[0]);
        }
     };
}

var words = [];
var x = prompt("Please type in the sentence that will be seperated.");
sentenceFinder(x);
```

Comment: I changed the subscript to substring... Thanks about the words array.

Comment: …and you probably shouldn't initialize `words` outside of the function at all. Make the variable local to `sentenceFinder`.